# Profiling iOS Today Widget (Instruments)

Tags: ios, instruments, today-extension

is that a way to analyze other targets in Instruments? I am trying to profile my widget target there but Instruments keep displaying a dialog saying "please take appropriate action to initiate the launch of `com.appId.widget`".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project to test and ran into the same issue - `waiting for widget`. However, the widget wasn't loading properly at all.

[image: Waiting for widget warning]

My first attempt was with Xcode 9 beta 3 and iOS 11, but then I tried again using Xcode 8 and iOS 10. I had to build and run the app and then the widget before getting the profile session to work.

[image: Successful Instruments run]

It ultimately did work! `Please take appropriate action` definitely needs to be improved with more helpful information from Apple.